# Congruence between $p^k$-th roots of unity modulo $r$ is coprime to $p$ is equality?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers, $p^k$ divides $q-1$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are $p^k$-th roots of unity. We consider $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^k}, \zeta_{q}]$, where $\zeta_{p^k}$ is primitive $p^k$-th root of unity and $\zeta_{q}$ is primitive $q$-th root of unity.

Then, if $r$ is coprime to $p$ and

$$\alpha \equiv \beta \bmod r\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^k}, \zeta_{q}]$$

$\alpha$ has to be equal to $\beta$.

How can this be proven? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working modulo $r$, which we may suppose to be a prime $\ne p$.
In a large enough finite field of characteristic $r$, there are
$p^k$ distinct $p^k$-th roots of unity. Thus distinct $p^k$-th roots of unity in a ring of cyclotomic integers reduce to distinct roots of unity
in a residue field of characteristic $r$.